# How to obtain CheckBox background color

Tags: android

I want to highlight a CheckBox by setting a custom color to its **background** and then fade that color into whatever was the original background color.

The issue is I don't know how to obtain the "colorTo" for ValueAnimator. Does CheckBox even have something that could be called a background? Or is it merely a text next to a tick-box?

The Checkbox is created at runtime, i.e. by calling its constructor. And I only set its text and an onClick handler, I do not set its bg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it has a background. Since you creating it at run time the background is not set so it is **Transparent** (Unless defined otherwise in Style).

For highlighting Button momentarily you can set a desired highlight color and animate the color from **Highlighted** color to **Background** color or simply animate it to **Transparent** color -> "#00000000"

P.S: You probably wont need this but to get background color of a `view` you can do this:

```
int color;
Drawable background = view.getBackground().mutate();

if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
   color = ((ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()).getColor();
}
```

The `mutate()` will clone your background so if you used this background in multiple places, with the change of background the other backgrounds won't change.

Comment: I will test this and come back to accept the answer. Thanks meanwhile!

Comment: Did it worked for you? Though it works only if you've set a color as background, if you declare your background type I can suggest other solutions too  ^^

Comment: Indeed I already figured there is a catch. I do not set my bg at all, which is probably why the color is black. The Checkbox is created at runtime, i.e. by calling its constructor, and I only set onClick handler and text.

Comment: Well then you can easily set the background color you want. Just Animate Value "00000000" to whatever your background color is ^^

Have a good programming

Comment: Reading my comment again, it is probably not very clear... The checkbox has no background color set, it appears to have white or transparent background. And when I perform what you suggested the (supposedly bg) color I get is black, which then results in the animator fading from "highlighted" color to black color, while it should go from "highlighted" to white/transparent.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what is the actual background color. It appears to be transparent.

Comment: I updated my answer to better match your updated question. let me know if it helps.